# Do I need to capitalize the M in "next Monday" or "I’m available on mondays"?

Tags: capitalization

I know that when I write Monday or Wednesday, I need to capitalize the first letter `M` or `W`.

But do I need to capitalize the M in "next Monday" or "I’m available on mondays"?

Comment: Did you do any research before asking this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first letter of a day of the week, a month, or a holiday is always a capital letter.

> I am available on Mondays.
>
> I will see you next Tuesday.
>
> I have seen some very cold Octobers.
>
> We met last April.
>
> I will go away next Easter.

The seasons are not capitalised unless they are being personified:

> I like to go on vacation in the summer.
>
> Ah, beautiful Spring, who shows her sweet beauty each April!

> Capitalization: the days of the week, the months of the year, and
> holidays, but not the seasons used generally
>
> Days, months, and holidays are always capitalized as these are proper nouns.

[Capitalisation (days, months) (Grammarly)](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/capitalization-the-days-of-the-week-the-months/)